# Bash wait does not work

Tags: bash, wait, child-process, gnu-parallel

Part of my code:

```
for i in "${r_arr[@]}"
do
    ${parallel_dir}parallel -j${cap} --semaphore --semaphorename a2_bootstrap_semaphore_${rnd} a2_exec ${i} ${temp_zmat_folder_path}${temp_zmat_folder}/ ${outs_folder}
done

wait
elapsed_time=$(($SECONDS - $start_time))

rm -rf "${temp_zmat_folder_path}${temp_zmat_folder}"
echo "Cleanup done."
echo "`date +%d-%m-%y` `date +%T`: All processing finished in ${elapsed_time} seconds!"
```

As you can see I'm starting a number of tasks using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). The problem is that cleanup (`rm`) is executed before last of the parallel tasks is even started. How to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: I don't see an asynchronous  process to wait for in your script. No `&` anywhere...

Comment: `wait` only waits for direct children of the shell; it cannot be used to `wait` on processes started by other processes (such as `parallel`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per their example, you should use this command to wait for all the started jobs to complete

```
parallel --semaphore --wait
```

Example (From man page):
The command `sem` is an alias for `parallel --semaphore`.

```
for i in *.log ; do
    echo $i
    sem -j+0 gzip $i ";" echo done
done
sem --wait
```

Comment: So the `wait` part has to be called from the `sem` itself. I missed that in docs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sam Daniels answer is entirely correct (except you need to wait for the  `--semaphorename` that you use), but `sem` is really slow. Consider using a function instead:

```
doit() {
  i="$1"
  a2_exec ${i} ${temp_zmat_folder_path}${temp_zmat_folder}/ ${outs_folder}
}
export -f doit
export temp_zmat_folder_path
export temp_zmat_folder
export outs_folder
${parallel_dir}parallel -j${cap} doit ::: "${r_arr[@]}"
```